# Can I ask my question in a new question cause my old one was down voted?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, downvotes, asking-questions

I do not understand why my question was down voted. My question has now evolved into an additional new question. I've asked such an additional new question in the past and linked to the previous question and I was told not to do this. How should I proceed?

[Link to my original question where I have edit the follow up question at the bottom, which wont get attention because my question has been down voted.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23786411/msvs-c-x86-debug-complains-about-char)

My new question is:

> If I do, it builds without issue:
>
> ```
> char** remotePlayersInMatch = 0;
> ```
>
> If I do it treats it as a function:
>
> ```
> char** remotePlayersInMatch(0);
> ```
>
> Can anyone explain why the second example is treated as a function? I was taught to initialize with () to make explicit the facts its constructing, distinguishing between assignment and construction. If I cannot follow my rule for char** should starting using = or stick to my () but use = for char**?

Comment: For what it's worth, Stack Overflow is probably not the best place to come to for your routine build and compilation errors.

Comment: I received a good answer in the form of a comment to my second question within my original question but have not received a full answer to my original question. I believe there are to many factors to the original question to give a clear and concise answer which is why no one has tried, however there were some valid points made as comments. I no longer need assistance on the issue since my second question has been answered.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

Just make sure that your new question is substantially improved and different.

If people can tell that they're the same, and if they're both low quality questions, and they looked at both of them, you will get backlash, but if they can't tell, than it's just like starting over.

You will get a faster and less hostile response from the new one than you would have if you had just edited your old question.

Some people on meta will tell you to just edit, but you're not going to see any benefit from "just editing" your question over posting a new one.  I don't feel like I can give you a suggestion like that that you're not going to be able to observe a benefit from.

Comment: This is a really fast road to a question ban, in addition to simply creating a ton more low quality content on the site that needs to get cleaned up.

Comment: Well pardon me for actually trying to get the OP better results rather than than force a pedantic dogma down his throat.   Old down-voted questions have a stigma on them that's a nuisance to do away with, and you all know it.

Comment: Because it's going to be so much better for him when he's question banned for posting the same bad question 4 times in a row...

Comment: My question is not bad. Do you understand my question?

Comment: @user3345413: obviously the downvoters disagreed. Even if the metric you're measuring it on is just "bad at avoiding downvotes", it's bad.

Comment: @Servy I was able to tell what he meant by his question(the meta question).  That's why I posted this answer the way I did.  Of course posting the same bad question.  Of course posting the **exact same** bad question is going to be bad for you, but you manage to compose a **good question**, than making a new question for that new, good question will almost always yield better results than changing your old question, whether the meta-heads like it or not.

Comment: @SamIam So your advocating the "do what's good for me and everyone else be damned" attitude?

Comment: @Servy If you've made a good question out of it, than it's good for everyone else too if you make a new question.

Comment: @Servy  I just can't bring myself to give advice to the OP that going to have a negative utility to him.  It makes me feel like a cult member asking someone to give away all of their possessions.

Comment: @SamIam That's exactly the way I feel about your answer, because in actual practice the *vast* majority of people aren't capable of editing their questions into great questions, so they end up just re-posting bad questions, and cause more problems for everyone involved, including themselves.  If it would only be people that fixed up their question from an awful one to a great one that did this, then it *wouldn't* be so bad, but that's not what happens.

Comment: I mark this question as the answer to my question because I believe it best applies in this specific case but am not in a position to condone creating new related questions in all cases.

Answer (score 11):

No, it is not appropriate to delete and re-ask your question just because it was downvoted.  Continuing this behavior will eventually lead to your account being banned from asking questions entirely.

You should be improving your existing question such that it meets the site's guidelines, not just making the same mistakes repeatedly.

Comment: I've never deleted and re-asked a question for being down voted, I've only ever deleted one question for being misguided and did not re-ask it. Why are you suggesting I have? There is nothing wrong with the question in this case, unless I cannot ask c++ compilation questions on stack overflow or you count the grammatical and aesthetic edits.

Comment: @user3345413 I wasn't suggesting that you have done it in the past.  I was simply stating that you shouldn't do it in the future.  You asked if doing so was okay, I'm telling you it's not.

Comment: I asked how I should proceed and implied I want to ask a second question which was not exactly but related to the first; because it was down voted. I implied unjustly down voted. I never suggested deleting it and asking the same question in a different way or with more information.

Comment: You specifically asked,  "Can I ask my question in a new question because the old one was downvoted."  This pretty strongly implies asking the same question.  Yes, if you have a new, entirely unrelated question to ask, you can ask a new question regardless of whether some unrelated question you asked was downvoted in the past or not.  Is your new question entirely unrelated from your previous question?

Comment: gnat edited my question from evolved to edited which does not mean the same thing. I then explicitly state I have a new question. I wanted to know if I could ask a new question and link to my old question. I want to ask advice on how to proceed with a question that evolved from my old topic. Which I did before and was reprimanded for. I wanted to know if there was a rule about linking or some such issue. I never suggest deleting the original question and asking the same question again.

Comment: @user3345413 Then the situation you're describing in this meta question is pretty radically different from what you are stating here.  If you really have a completely different question, rather than a refurbished version of the same question, then yes, you would ask that in a new question, rather than editing your question to completely change what is being asked.

Comment: @Servy, is there truly a trigger on accounts that only ask questions?  I think it's a great idea, but I *thought* there was a filter that they had to be deadbeat questions before the software intervened pejoratively.

Comment: @GayotFow The OP is describing questions that are being downvoted due to their quality.  It's a pretty safe bet that re-asking the same question is reasonably likely to have the same result.  Having a lot of downvoted/deleted questions triggers the question ban.  Having upvotes questions, even without answers, will not.